# Weird behavior of template and google maps

Tags: html, google-maps, debugging, hover, visibility

I downloaded this template from themeforest: http://themeforest.net/item/-medic-medical-health-and-hospital-html5-theme/full_screen_preview/8331329

Move your mouse over navigation item "Contact" and you will see a google map. Remember position of the map. Then close contact item and move your mouse over position, where map was placed. Contact window should appear again, without opening it by clicking on Contact item. I am unsuccessfuly trying to repair this bug. Is there a way how to do it?

Comment: the template is in a iframe, have you put it online in your own server so that I can look at it

Comment: here: http://www.scsppza.betaverzia.sk/html/

Comment: All scripts are in .min version. I do not know where the menu is managed but you can hide the maps when the menu is hidden and show it before it is showed, that will solve the bug. Do `$('.map').hide()` when the menu is hidden and `$('.map')show()` before the menu is showed

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I did it as you suggested.

Comment: Ok, so I'm creating an answer with my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the maps when the menu is hidden and show it before it is showed, that will solve the bug. Do `$('.map').hide()` when the menu is hidden and `$('.map').show()` before the menu is showed